# Does memoir and geometry mix well?

Tags: memoir, geometry

I have somewhere along the way gotten the impression that the `geometry` package and the `memoir` class handles the page-setup a bit differently, but I have also gotten the impression that they do not mix well, that is, you should not use `geometry` if your class is `memoir`.  Is there any truth in this?

Comment: A quick google search for memoir and geometry indicate most everyone uses the memoir commands. However, the memoir user manual reads "The class also provides functions similar to those provided by the following packages, although the commands are different: crop, fancyhdr, geometry, sidecap, subfigure, titlesec. **You can use these packages if you wish, or just use the capabilities of the memoir class.**" (emphasis mine)

Comment: One should not, however, do both at the same time.

Comment: Moreover, one reason to use Memoir is the facilities it provides for page layout and the typographic basis on which it is built. If you then go and use **geometry**, you cannot have *that* reason to use Memoir. And if you use enough of those packages, then you probably have no reason to use it at all.

Comment: @MikeRenfro: I also got the impression (from a Google search) that most people use the memoir commands, and I had even read the part you quote in memman, but I still picked up the impression somewhere, and I wanted to know what it was about.  I also found the answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112209/paper-size-with-geometry-in-memoir-latex-vs-pdflatex), where the use of geometry is discouraged, but the reason is not given.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: It might be the case that the problem is to somehow use both geometry and the features of memoir, which is actually the case in the question in the question I referred to in my comment to Mike.

Comment: @cfr: I usually use the features of memoir myself, but I sometimes find the need to make changes on a single page or on a few pages, and I have had a hard time understanding how this is done using memoir.  I think I will try this in another question.

Comment: So I gather that using geometry with memoir is not a problem, but that it might cause problem it you mix the features of memoir and geometry.  In case this is correctly understood, I would be happy to accept an answer with this, and maybe a short explanation of why this mixing is bad.