# Changing PDF paper size mid-document in memoir

Tags: memoir

Previously, with the `memoir` class (tested with TeX Live 2017), I've been able to change the PDF page size mid-document with (for example):

```
\makeatletter
\clearpage
\setstocksize{13in}{8.5in}
\settrimmedsize{13in}{8.5in}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.79in}{0.79in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.79in}{0.79in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\ch@ngetext
\fixpdflayout
\makeatother
```

At some point (tested with TeX Live 2019), the `memoir` class has changed.  Now, I get a warning about `\fixpdflayout` not doing anything anymore, and the `memoir` manual says:

> In earlier versions we had macros \fixpdflayout and \fixdvipslayout that held some of the code
>   needed to emit this data. With the newer engines like LuaLaTeX, this became unfeasible thus they we discontinued (their use now emit a warning).

And of course, the page size does not change in the resulting PDF.

I've previously read that the `geometry` class would allow me to change the page size, but that its use with `memoir` is not recommended.  If that's true, is there a "good" way to change the PDF page size mid-document with a modern `memoir`?

Comment: Why don't you use the geometry-package for that?

Comment: @TimHilt Well, I have read that it is not recommended to use both geometry and memoir (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288716/does-memoir-and-geometry-mix-well and various other Q&As on tex.se), so I have avoided using both.

Comment: The opinions seem to be mixed on that topic; at least when referring to the mentioned thread. If i were you i would try using it with geometry. This would obviously be the easiest workaround. If you mention something strange or unwanted in the resulting pdf you know where to look.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will give it a go.  I guess I have no real alternative :).

Comment: As always please always provide a full example, not sniplets. That makes testing faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\let\fixpdflayout\mem@fixpagelayout
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you daleif, this works in the newer version, and apologies for omitting the full example in the question.